# Problem in displaying dropdown box

Tags: html, jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ADD URL Sources</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="Test1.jsp" method="post">


<br><br><select name="source" onchange="">
<option value="rss">RSS LINK</option>
<option value="other">OTHER LINK</option>
</select>       


<br><br> Enter URL to be added 

 <input type="text" name="url" size=50>


<br/><br>Enter the Source Name of the 

URL<t><input type="text" name="source" size=50><br/><br>


 <input type="Submit" name="submit1" value="Add URL in DB">
 </form>   

  </body>
   </html>
```

I am using the above html code in a .jsp extension file.
While running the file, I can successfully get two input boxes that I have mentioned but not the dropdown box(select tag) in the output.

What modifications should be done. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code on a Tomcat server and everything displays just fine. Just out of curiosity, try re-starting your server and see if the dropdown comes up.

You may also want your input tags to be like this `<input type="text" value="value" name="name" />`, make them self-closing tags.

Comment: No problem, make sure you accept the answer if this works for you. Usually I use "Eclipse" to do my JSP development, and in there depending on your server clicking on "Publish" will also make your JSP changes get reflected.